# Selenium Webdriver - script is not running when baseurl contains IP address of the application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have following code:

```java
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
baseUrl = "http://192.160.11.2:8081";
driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(ffsEmail);
```

When running this code, the Firefox browser opens. But without entering the baseurl it gets closed without running the code.

Running the same code with "www.google.com" works, please i need help to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Firefox and WD are you using?

Comment: Can you hit that URL on the browser without any problems outside of using webdriver?

Comment: yes, that is the application I am using and its working with the url. My Firefox version is 20.0 and WD version 2.31.0.

Comment: Hmm..Interesting that it doesnt work. I could get it working for all other browsers except FF. Even FF will work if you use a RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.FirefoxDriver()). YOu need to keep the server up though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your `driver.getCurrentUrl()` returns `http://192.160.11.2:8081/` 
but this IP is the "welcome page" of jboss server. So i you'll find nothing except some html tags..